spring-cloud-contract and spring-boot-starter-amqp (Rabbit), problem with producer: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named available
I'm having trouble implementing Spring Cloud Contract on the producer side to generate contracts for event triggering via RabbitMQ. I`m using spring-boot-starter-amqp as interface to RabbitMq.
The tests generated by the framework are failing with the following error:
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car-interest-ex' available
My contract (Groovy DSL) is defined as follows:
Contract.make {
    description 'Should trigger message about interest in a car'
    label 'car_interest'
    input {
        triggeredBy('carInterestTriggered()')
    }
    outputMessage {
        sentTo("car-interest-ex")
        headers {
            header("amqp_receivedRoutingKey", "")
        }
        body([
                carId  : 1,
                event: "CAR_INTEREST"
        ])
    }
}

This resulted in the following test provided by the framework:
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class GeneralTest extends GeneralBase {
    @Inject ContractVerifierMessaging contractVerifierMessaging;
    @Inject ContractVerifierObjectMapper contractVerifierObjectMapper;

    @Test
    public void validate_sendCarInterestMessage() throws Exception {
        // when:
            carInterestTriggered();

        // then:
            ContractVerifierMessage response = contractVerifierMessaging.receive("car-interest-ex",
                    contract(this, "sendCarInterestMessage.yml"));
            assertThat(response).isNotNull();

        // and:
            assertThat(response.getHeader("amqp_receivedRoutingKey")).isNotNull();
            assertThat(response.getHeader("amqp_receivedRoutingKey").toString()).isEqualTo("");

        // and:
            DocumentContext parsedJson = JsonPath.parse(contractVerifierObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(response.getPayload()));
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['carId']").isEqualTo(1);
            assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['event']").isEqualTo("CAR_INTEREST");
    }

}

My test base class is configured as follows:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureMessageVerifier
public class GeneralBase extends BaseContractTest {

    @Autowired
    CarPublisher carPublisher;

    @Autowired
    Exchange exchange;

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public void carInterestTriggered() {
        var payload = CarInterestPayload.create(String.valueOf(1));
        carPublisher.sendMessage(payload);
    }

}

My Publisher is written as follows:
@Component
@Log4j2
public class CarPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Exchange exchange;

    public void sendMessage(CarInterestPayload payload) {
        try {
            log.info("payload send: %s".formatted(payload));
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange.getName(),"", payload);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("message not send: %s".formatted(payload));
        }
    }
}

And finally, my Rabbit configuration is as follows:
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqProducerConfig {

    static final String exchange = "car-interest-ex";

    @Bean
    public Exchange directExchangeCarInterest() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        var template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }
}

Here are the dependencies I am using:

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <packageWithBaseClasses>com.tech.community.cars.contract</packageWithBaseClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


The versions are:
spring boot version:3.2.3
spring cloud version: 2023.0.0
spring cloud contract version:4.1.0
spring amqp version: 3.2.3
java: 17

When I run mvn clean install, the tests fail as mentioned above with the error NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car-interest-ex' available.
The stack trace of the error is as follows:
2024-07-24 17:42:18,938 ERROR main o.s.c.c.v.m.i.SpringIntegrationStubMessages:74 - Exception occurred while trying to read a message from  a channel with name [car-interest-ex]
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car-interest-ex' available

...

java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car-interest-ex' available
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.SpringIntegrationStubMessages.receive(SpringIntegrationStubMessages.java:76)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.SpringIntegrationStubMessages.receive(SpringIntegrationStubMessages.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration$2.receive(ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration$2.receive(ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:72)
    at com.tech.community.cars.contract.GeneralTest.validate_sendCarInterestMessage(GeneralTest.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'car-interest-ex' available

Could you please help me understand where the error is? What do I need to do to successfully run the tests on the Producer side?
I have already tried changing the RabbitMQ configurations, binding the queue on the producer side. I also looked for information in the Spring Cloud Contract documentation, but I couldn't make any progress.
